# ASP.NET MVC multiple models in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have the following models
Patient Class:

```
public class Patient
{
    public int PatientID { get; set; }

    public virtual Salutation salutation { get; set; }
    public int SalutationID { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public string RegNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegDate { get; set; }
    public string Occupation { get; set; }
}
```

VatalSigns Class

```
public class VitalSign
{
    public int VitalSignID { get; set; }
    public string Sign { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Lower Limit")]
    public int? LowerHold { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Upper Limit")]
    public int? UpperHold { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Unit Of Measurment")]
    public string Units { get; set; }
}
```

PV class that stores VitalSigns for each patient

```
public class PVSign
{

    public long PVSignId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Patient")]
    public int PatientID { get; set; }
    public VitalSign VitalSigns { get; set; }
    //public IList<VitalSign> VitalSigns { get; set; }
    public Patient patient { get; set; }

}
```

Now the problem I have is that I have not been able to get display on one from to enter the details.  I want to select the Patient and the different Vitals signs will appear and I will save the ones I need to the PVSign table.

I have tired all sorts of samples from the web.  You can see from the code below, this is the index stub:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var pVSigns = db.PVSigns.Include(p => p.patient).Include(p => p.PVSignId).Include(p => p.VitalSigns);
    //var pVSigns = from o in db.Patients join o2 in db.PVSigns
    //List<object> myModel = new List<object>();
    //myModel.Add(db.Patients.ToList());
    //myModel.Add(db.VitalSigns.ToList());

    //return View(myModel);
    return View(pVSigns.ToList());
}
```

How to I solve this issue.  I am new to MVC, if it was Webforms, I would have been through with this project.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried creating a view model?

Comment: why not encapsulate all your models into one and then pass it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no single answer(solution) to this(your) problem. It depends on how you want to design/build/achieve your solution.
The simple, brute solution : Just have a view model as a wraper that has as his properties the classes(models) you made and work around that,

```
public class FullPatientDetailsViewModel
{
    public Patient { get; set;}
    public List<PVSign> PatientPvSigns { get; set;} // Patien PV Signs
}
```

Or use just a PatientViewModel and load his PVSigns async with Ajax.
There is no simple best solution, it all depends about what do you want to achieve as a bigger picture.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554255/how-can-i-do-this-multiples-models-on-view-mvc-5/36581311#36581311). As Alexandru mentioned, the easiest and most straightforward way would be to wrap your models inside a `ViewModel`. You can read about other ways to implement this [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687061/Multiple-Models-in-a-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-MVC).